Well Crafted Patterns To Access Instanced Members Through Static Functions Without The Singleton?
I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to have access to a static function that would operate on instanced values without implementing a singleton. I'm not sure it's possible, I've personally never seen it done. Even the alternatives I've seen essentially mimic a singleton in a sense, like a static delegate that's assigned at some sort of initialization step, replacing the object instance with a function instance. It may seem like a silly question, but the domain I'm working in does not allow for the type of singletons I prefer to use due to things like serialization and persistence. Even suggestions and guesses would be appreciated if you can't think of an established pattern or even just one you've come up with that you thought worked well.
Essentially everything boils down to a basic pattern, which is some member that is static and then initialized at some point so it can be accessed from a static function.  All the possible alternatives I've come across seem like they're pretending not to be singletons. Not that I have anything against them, they have their place. I'm certainly not one of the people who goes around repeating 'singletons are for simpletons' because they heard some professor say it and feel smart. But again, due to the environment and problem domain, the way singletons are handled, makes me want to avoid them in most cases.

A static method handles only one instance at a time.  That is what static means. You need to change the static method to a non static method.

Of course it's possible, you just need to add the instance as another parameter to your static function. But I'm not sure that's actually what you meant, despite the confusing question. How about you show an actual example of what you are trying to do? Because at the moment it's really not clear.

How about you define your (non-static) instances / values in a dependency injection context, and then use a static class to get the instances injected?
Then you can operate on the values from a static context.
Seems like a valid option, and not at all singleton-pattern unless you consider the dependency injection context a singleton as well
Edit: Its against official guidelines

Not really worried about guidelines. I've seen plenty that are either outdated or simply there to prevent people that don't understand why they're there from doing something 'dangerous'. I would ask for a bit of boiler plate just so I understand precisely what you're saying, I can see a few ways on interpreting this. A lot of people I've spoken to mean construction params when they say dependency injections I'm curious how you see it going in a static class. I appreciate the time you took in answer, so that's why the up vote.

Not to say that's the only method of dependency injection, just an example of why I was asking for clarification. Unfortunately, I'm in Unity so a lot of standard stuff does not apply.

From some quick research, it  seems you may be able to use https://github.com/Mathijs-Bakker/Extenject for this need. Specifically you want to see how it handles method injection, which is what i was referring to. That is, access to your instanced types through injection into the method parameters. (In your case, in a static class)

Unfortunately, I haven't been around stack overflow in a while due to its uhh.. contemporary state. However, I would like to say that essentially all the alternatives I've found are essentially some permutation of a singleton. You can use events or actions if you don't need an actual reference. However, most alternatives are like creating a static class as almost a facade and then populating (what I refer to as a registrar) with that instance. There's at least separation of concern. Everything ends up being a different permutation of singleton, other than events and delegates if possible.
